# How to correctly use istream::get ( char* s, streamsize n, char delim );

Tags: c++

The documentation says:

```
istream::get ( char* s, streamsize n, char delim );

// Extracts characters from the stream and stores them as a 
// c-string into the array beginning at s
```

I tried to analyze what this function does. It takes a pointer "by value". That is it cannot allocate dynamic memory and set the pointer `s` to it. It can only change what the pointer `s` points to.

But if the function cannot perform dynamic memory allocation, how can it return an output whose length is not known? How should I use this function? Should I preallocate memory and pass the pointer to it as `s` and then delete it by myself?

Comment: Which documentation? In addition, the documentation is actually pretty clear

Comment: Ok I get it now, Thank you! http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Comment: `cplusplus.com` is bad, you should use this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: If you want dynamic memeory allocation, you should try `getline(istream&, std::string&)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should preallocate memory (pointed to by `s`) of size `n`, pass that `s` to first and  `n` to second parameter of the function. This way, `get` will read maximum `n` bytes (including terminating null) and copy them to buffer pointed to by `s`

If your buffer is local (an array on the stack, lets say), you don't have to delete it (in fact you can't) However if it is dynamic (i.e, allocated by new[], malloc, operator new or whatever) then you have to free it accordingly.

example:

```
const int n = 50;
char *s = new char[n];

cin.get(s, n);
//...

delete []s;
```

note: although this is valid, as others commented, better use `std::string` instead.

Comment: This is really bad code. [**Do not use `new` here**](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/).

Comment: Aren't you missing a 0 byte for that string?

Comment: @KonradRudolph why is it really bad? because new is used at all, or because in this case there's sth wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling new. `char s[50];` would be better.

Comment: @Loki just an example, no specific reason. but why char s[50] is better do you think?

Comment: I mean you're missing the null terminator for the string `\n`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph i see, yes i agree that it's better idea to use std::string. but it's still an example so i will leave it.

Comment: @David http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~kev/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/iostream/istream/get.html see "An ending null character is automatically appended at the end of the content stored in s."

Comment: @AliVeli: Its exception safe and does not require you to do manual memory management (which is not C++ like at all). If you want to dynamically allocate memory you should be using a container like `std::vector<char>` (which is exception safe).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes I agree. But is the link helpful (I can't get passed the splash screen).

Comment: @Loki Maybe a new browser is in order then (Opera is sadly also not supported – I’m simply using [Google’s slide template](https://code.google.com/p/io-2012-slides/), feel free to file a bug report if that annoys you enough). Or just append `.pdf` to the URL.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The advance and backward links are invisible to me. If I click just to the right of the splash screen area it advances. But it took some clicks to find. I am using the latest firefox so I hope that is modern enough.

Comment: @Loki There aren’t any visible links, it’s a *presentation*, not a website, you use your arrow keys.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is clear:

> stores them as a c-string into the array beginning at s

– `s` has to point to a valid array that’s big enough to accommodate the read string.

> how can it return an output whose length is not known

The *maximum length* is known, it’s `n` (actually `n - 1`, since one character is reserved for the null termination of the C string).

However, given your questions it’s probably more appropriate to use [the `std::string` overload of `getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Thanks! getline is indeed more appropriate for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should use it like this:

```
const int size = 10;
char s[size]; //large enough to fit string
stream.get(&s[0], size, '\n');
```

You preallocate the buffer you need and make sure it's large enough to fit target string.